# Column Values not Returned (GoogleSheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[Sheetlink](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eC3oTRd_ROOjqRczjba-l9IQRdEa70WIz4BKNTiTTeA/edit?usp=sharing)

Column Values for Col_K(11) are returned as an EMPTY ARRAY however the previous column values Col_J(10) are returned fine.

Whats Missing?

CODE:

```
function oiNotif() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('OiNotif');  
  var condCol;
  var triggerPrice;
  
 
  condCol = sheet.getRange(2,10,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  triggerPrice = sheet.getRange(2,11,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  
  Logger.log(' condCol =  %s',condCol);
  Logger.log(' triggerPrice =  %s',triggerPrice);

}
```

Log :

```
condCol =  [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [true], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [true], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [true], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [true], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [false], [false], [false], []] 



triggerPrice =  [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried some basic troubleshooting for this? (e.g creating a new script file, making a copy of the sheet and using the same code or trying a different browser or using an incognito browser). I replicated it on my end and it works fine.

Comment: Using Edge Browser ... which browser was the script tested on ?

Comment: Should be Sheet.getLastRow() - 1

Comment: @srt111 I used chrome browser initially, but just tested it again using Microsoft Edge, and it works fine still. Try making a copy of the sheet or creating a new script file

Comment: how do you call the function ? Could you add a little delay (with `Utilities.sleep`) ? The column might take some time to compute values and at the time you're reading it, it's not done yet

Comment: Script worked fine on Brave Browser.